# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_20 to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (3,)

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have read through other stack overflow but it didnt satisfy my problem. Im doing object localization and I expect my model produce four outputs which are the x1,y1,x2,y2 for the bounding box. But it keeps showing me the value error. Is it something wrong with my model or my datasets are wrong?
model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding = 'same' ,activation = 'relu', input_shape= (image_width,image_height,image_channels)),
keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)),
keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding = 'same',activation = 'relu'),
keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)),
keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding = "same",activation = 'relu'),
keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)),
keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
keras.layers.Flatten(),
keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = 'relu'),
keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
keras.layers.Dense(4,activation="relu")
])
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

train and validation data generator:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rotation_range = 15,
rescale = 1./255,
shear_range = 0.1,
zoom_range = 0.2,
horizontal_flip = True,
width_shift_range = 0.1,
height_shift_range = 0.1
)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe = train_df,
directory = "/mydrive/Object-Classification-and-Localization-with-TensorFlow-master/training_images",
x_col = 'filename',
y_col = 'name',
target_size = (128,128),
class_mode = 'categorical',
batch_size = batch_size
)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe = validate_df,
directory = "/mydrive/Object-Classification-and-Localization-with-TensorFlow-master/training_images",
x_col = 'filename',
y_col = 'name',
target_size = (128,128),
class_mode = 'categorical',
batch_size = batch_size
)
```

dataset format(total shape for the dataframe = (1488,9)):

```
    filename        width   height  depth   name    xmin    ymin    xmax    ymax
    cucumber_1.jpg  227      227     3     cucumber  23      42      206    199
```